# Self Registration Error - Company Tag

Tags: community, user-registration

When I try to self register a user, I get an error and then an email that states

"There was an error in registering a user in site ****SITENAME****. The error message is: Please specify the Company Tag for this User."

The account is a partner account, self registration is enabled, default account is set to the partner account. Owner of the partner account has a role. A profile is selected that is a community user profile.

I am using the standard self register lightning component.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your user object has a required field Company Tag.

You may either remove the required custom field if not necessary

or

- customize the self reg visualforce page to add this field
- Also, customize CommunitiesSelfRegController, to pass this value for user creation.